# Redirect Url with a href or window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, opencart

I using Opencart Version 1.5.1.

Example my website url : www.website.com

and i set redirect link in controller :

```
$this->data['google'] = "https://accounts.google.com";
// this is url for login account google,so i can't change the htaccess
```

Then i call it in View :

```
<div class="omb_login">
    <div class="omb_socialButtons">
        //another button
        <button class="btngoogle">
            <i class="fa fa-google" data-size="icon"></i>
                <a href="<?php echo $google; ?>" class="google" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">Google</a>
                // it's like <a href="https://accounts.google.com" ......
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's work on Chrome `// link = https://accounts.google.com`

but not work for Mozilla Firefox `// nothing happen when i click.`

I tried fix using `function on click`.

```
$(function() {
  $('.btngoogle').on('click', function () {
        var temp = ($(".google").attr("href"));
        $(location).attr('href',temp);
  });
});
```

when i click www.website.com/https://accounts.google.com.

Any one know how to fix (how make mozilla work for a href?) or (the redirect url ?) ?

Comment: Do you see anything in your console? (Press F12 for developer tools in your browser).

Comment: try <button onclick="window.location='<?php echo $google; ?>';" class="google">Google</button>